Why UPI deep link payments not working to merchant UPI address
Why upi deep link payments not working to merchant upi vpa address? I have so many merchant accounts, all are working as a deep link integration, but after April 1 2024 suddenly stopped working. I tried all merchand upi address but no use. Please help me
Help me to what is the reason?

Upi mode 04 and 05 not allow from April 2024 https://www.npci.org.in/PDF/npci/upi/circular/2024/UPI-OC-76A-Revision-in-transaction-limits-based-on-Merchant-&-transaction-types.pdf

so does that means now only way to use upi is through payment gateway??
